# XML parsering enclosure

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

i have two of "enclosure" with deferent "type"...
how can i make the parser "audio/mpeg" parsing the URL OF .mp3 to play it with the MediaPlayer

```
<enclosure url="http://www.radiozerosix.fr/upload/podcasts/audios/5784338b042d41.79777284.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" length="5986913"/>
<enclosure url="http://www.radiozerosix.fr/upload/podcasts/photos/main/5784338b047468.88036252_mini.png" type="image/png" length="131302"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy. You should be able to get the URL from each enclosure element using the attributes dictionary in NSXMLParser's `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` method.

**You could retrieve it like this:**

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure"]) {
       [self.mediaURLArray addObject:attributeDict[@"url"];
   }
}
```

If you **only need the audio file's URL**, you could also filter for that:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure"]) {
        if ([attributeDict[@"type"] isEqualToString:@"audio/mpeg"]) {
                self.mediaURL = attributeDict[@"url"];
        }
    }
}
```

After doing that, you should be able to stream that audio file using your mediaURL property.

Comment: Thank you very much bro :D .. it's Worked :D